# Re-open queue has really old posts appearing now

Tags: support, reopen-queue

I'm seeing items in the re-open queue that haven't been touch for a year or more.

For example one I'm looking at was asked Jul 23 2012 at 15:40, then closed four minutes later.  The community user has an edit on it to put in the "possible duplicate" message.

Why is this post (and ones like it) entering the re-open queue now?  Community edits probably shouldn't trigger the re-open queue.  Even if they did, why a year later?

Comment: I have seen the same thing.

Comment: We know about this, we're looking at it - recent changes to criteria to get posts into that queue are probably to blame, will post when it's fixed :)

Comment: On the plus side, I now have the distinction of handing the only re-open review ever on this meta site.  :-)

Comment: I think you linked to the wrong question in your post?

Comment: Yes wrong URL on the link.  I removed the link since I can't get back to see what I did in the queue.

Answer (score 1):

The criteria for posts to appear in that queue has been changed, so that posts that are *likely* to have been improved actually make it in. One such criteria was also considering third party edits, or edits to the post by someone other than the OP that didn't also flag/vote to have the question closed.

It's being adjusted, and a bit of stuff churned - sorry about the noise :)